# Running multiple statements with MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'd like to run multiple statements with one command. Is it possible:

This is the SQL command:

```
UPDATE toggle SET state='0' WHERE feature_name=‘feature_1;
UPDATE toggle SET state=‘1’ WHERE feature_name=‘feature_2’;
UPDATE toggle SET state=‘1’ WHERE feature_name=‘feature_3’;
```

For one command I run something like that:

```
import MySQLdb
myDB = MySQLdb.connect(host=host, port=db_port, user=user, passwd=db_password, db=db)
cHandler = myDB.cursor()
cHandler.execute(query)
```

But this obviously works only for a single statement

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameterized query and [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html).